# Kerberos Authentication Error - When loading Hadoop Config Files from SharedPath

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos

I am developing an Java Application and this application is saving a result data to HDFS. The java Application should run in my windows machine.

We using Kerberos Authentication and we placed a keytab file in NAS drive. And we saved Hadoop config Files in the same NAS drive.

My issues is when I load the Hadoop config files from NAS drive, Its throwing me some Authetication error, But my application is running fine if I load the config files from my local File System  (I also saved the config files inside  C:\Hadoop)

Below is my working code snippet. **(keytab file in NAS, Hadoop config files in local file system)**

```
static String KeyTabPath = "\\\\path\\2\\keytabfile\\name.keytab"
Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://xxx.xx.xx.com:8020");
        config.addResource(new Path("C:\\Hadoop\\core-site.xml"));
        config.addResource(new Path("C:\\Hadoop\\hdfs-site.xml"));
        config.addResource(new Path("C:\\Hadoop\\mapred-site.xml"));
        config.addResource(new Path("C:\\Hadoop\\yarn-site.xml"));
        config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
        config.set("fs.file.impl",org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
        // Kerberos Authentication
        config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
        UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("name@xx.xx.COM",KeyTabPath);
```

I tried loading config files also from the NAS drive but getting kerberos authentication error. 
Below is the code snippet which throwing error **(Keytab file in NAS and Hadoop config files also in NAS)**

```
static String KeyTabPath = "\\\\path\\2\\keytabfile\\name.keytab"
Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://xxx.xx.xx.com:8020");
        config.addResource(new Path("\\\\NASDrive\\core-site.xml"));
        config.addResource(new Path("\\\\NASDrive\\hdfs-site.xml"));
        config.addResource(new Path("\\\\NASDrive\\mapred-site.xml"));
        config.addResource(new Path("\\\\NASDrive\\yarn-site.xml"));
        config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
        config.set("fs.file.impl",org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
        // Kerberos Authentication
        config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
        UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("name@xx.xx.COM",KeyTabPath);
```

**Below is the Error Message**

```
java.io.IOException: Login failure for name@XX.XX.COM from keytab \\NASdrive\name.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal principal name name@XX.XX.COM: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName$NoMatchingRule: No rules applied to name@XX.XX.COM
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:962)
    at Appname.ldapLookupLoop(Appname.java:111)
    at Appname.main(Appname.java:70)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal principal name name@XX.XX.COM: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName$NoMatchingRule: No rules applied to name@XX.XX.COM
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginModule.commit(UserGroupInformation.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:953)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal principal name name@XX.XX.COM: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName$NoMatchingRule: No rules applied to name@XX.XX.COM
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.User.<init>(User.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.User.<init>(User.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginModule.commit(UserGroupInformation.java:197)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName$NoMatchingRule: No rules applied to name@XX.XX.COM
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName.getShortName(KerberosName.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.User.<init>(User.java:48)
    ... 16 more
Jul 06, 2016 4:29:14 PM com.XX.it.logging.JdkMapper info
INFO:  IO Exception occured: java.io.IOException: Login failure for name@XX.XX.COM from keytab \\NASdrive\name.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal principal name name@XX.XX.COM: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName$NoMatchingRule: No rules applied to name@XX.XX.COM
```

So issues seems to be loading the config file. My application reading the keytab file fine from NAS drive, but not the Hadoop config files. What could be the issue. I checked all the NAS Drive permissions and file permissions. Everthing is fine. I dont know where the issue is. please anyone help me to find out the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing "DEFAULT" rule for `auth_to_local` kerberos principal name transformation.

> > org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName$NoMatchingRule: 
> >     No rules applied to

See example here -

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html#Mapping_from_Kerberos_principals_to_OS_user_accounts

so basically just add word "DEFAULT" at the very end of `hadoop.security.auth_to_local` in your `core-site.xml`.

Also check `auth_to_local` in [Kerberos documentation](http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html) .

PS. Here's [where this exception happens in Hadoop codebase](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-3.2.0-RC1/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-auth/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/security/authentication/util/KerberosName.java#L429), in case if you're interested to dig deeper on this subject.